# Reading and printing UTF-8 symbols from a file in C++

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8

I've faced an issue and couldn't find an answer on the internet. Even though I found many similar questions, none of the answers worked for me. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

So part of my code is:

```
wstring books[50];
wstring authors[50];
wstring genres[50];
wstring takenBy[50];
wstring additional;
bool taken[50];
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
wifstream fd("bookList.txt");
i = 0;
while (!fd.eof())
{
    getline(fd, books[i]);
    getline(fd, authors[i]);
    getline(fd, genres[i]);
    getline(fd, takenBy[i]);
    fd >> taken[i];
    getline(fd, additional);
    i++;
}
```

What I need, is to read a text file encoded in UTF-8 with C++. But, when I read the file, those wide strings are changed and when I print them, the output text is absolutely different.

Input:

> *ąčę*

Output:

> *ÄÄÄ*

How do I avoid it and read the text correctly?

Comment: So that we are not doomed to simply repeat all the answers that "didn't work for you", perhaps you can expand on why existing solutions are not applicable?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, as I told, I need to get and print UTF-8 characters from a file, but as I tried out the answers and advice given in other places, they either didn't work at all or didn't do what I needed it to do, for example, as I have already written, strings lose UTF-8 characters and I want to know how I could avoid that loss.

Comment: Update your question don't post a comment please.  And can you state what platform you are running on?  Unicode still has some platform dependencies.

Comment: If you are using Windows console, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500

Comment: It's OT, but please note that `while (!fd.eof())` could lead to [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/4944425).

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 6):

[UTF-8 is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (probably) not in wide strings. Read about [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). UTF-8 use **8 bits bytes** (sometimes *several* of them) to encode Unicode characters. So in C++ an unicode character is parsed from a sequence of 1 to 6 bytes (i.e. `char`-s).

You need some UTF-8 parser and the C11 or C++11 standards don't provide any. So you need some external library. Look into [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) (which is a simple C UTF-8 parsing library) or something else ([Qt](http://qt.io/), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-unichar-isspace), [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), ...). You could decide to parse and convert UTF-8 into wide [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) (using `u32string`-s and `char32_t`) and backwards, or you'll better decide to work internally in UTF-8 (using `std::string` and `char`)

Hence you'll parse and print sequences of `char`-s (using UTF-8 encoding) and your program would use plain `std::string`-s and plain `char`-s (not `std::wstring` or `wchar_t`) but process *UTF-8 sequences* ...

Comment: It's downright depressing reading the sentence *C11 or C++11 standards don't provide any*

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html):

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_UNICODE
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit;

int main()
{
    std::string in("ąčę");
    std::string out;
    qi::parse(in.begin(), in.end(), +unicode::char_, out);
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

The following example reads a sequence of tuples (book, authors, takenBy):

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_UNICODE
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::spirit;

int main()
{
    std::string in("Book_1\nAuthors_1\nTakenBy_1\n"\
                   "Book ąčę\nAuthors_2\nTakenBy_2\n");
    std::vector<
        std::tuple<
            std::string, /* book */
            std::string, /* authors */
            std::string  /* takenBy */
        > 
    > out;
    auto ok = qi::parse(in.begin(), in.end(),
                        *(
                               +(unicode::char_ - qi::eol) >> qi::eol /* book */
                            >> +(unicode::char_ - qi::eol) >> qi::eol /* authors */
                            >> +(unicode::char_ - qi::eol) >> qi::eol /* takenBy */
                        ),
                        out);
    if(ok)
    {
        for(auto& entry : out)
        {
            std::string book, authors, takenBy;
            std::tie(book, authors, takenBy) = entry;
            std::cout << "book: "    << book    << std::endl
                      << "authors: " << authors << std::endl
                      << "takenBy: " << takenBy << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It's only a demo using `std::tuple` and an unnamed parser, which is the third parameter of `qi::parse`. You can use a [struct](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html) instead of the tuple to represent *books, authors, genres* and etc. The unnamed parser may be replaced by a [grammar](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/roman_numerals.html#spirit.qi.tutorials.roman_numerals.grammars) and you can read the content of the file into a string to be passed to `qi::parse`.